# Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

newbie here. I try to run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I get these errors:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (usin  
  g password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_  
  schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)                              


In Connector.php line 67:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (usin  
  g password: YES)
```

This is what is contained in my database.php and .env files respectively:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

---

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

---

My DB name is homestead and host is localhost yet it's still giving error messages.

And this is what it looks like in myPhpAdmin user accounts overview page:
[image: user permissions?]

How would I fix this?

Comment: When I encountered this problem it was my database name.I used the one on my local instead of the one I set in the cpanel.

Comment: @hungrykoala Thanks for the reply. What name should I give for my database? (new to this stuff)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `homestead` without any changes then the default host for the homestead machine is `192.168.10.10`.

**Change**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

**to**

```
DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
```

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but it gave me the error saying `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out`

Answer (score 0):

This means that either your database username or password is wrong. If you are on windows the default DB_USERNAME is root and password is empty. Try correcting your configuration in .env file.